# MATLAB -Draw a rectangle ROI on a video input

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing

How do I specify/set/define a visible Region of Interest on a video and then perform all the processing just inside that Region Of Interest. Something like this:

[image]

(Source:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPmG30byCyc)

As you can see, all the processing from detection to tracking happens just inside the ROI. I wish to implement the same setting.

All I have so far is iterating through the video input and showing it in a video player:

```
reader = vision.VideoFileReader('rotatedjustright.mp4');
viewer = vision.VideoPlayer;
while ~isDone(reader)

    I = step(reader);
    step(viewer,I);

end
```

I guess somewhere inside the loop the ROI is specified? Then all processing from background subtraction to tracking will just happen inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A starting point would be to read in a single frame, then draw a ROI; from this you can create a mask (matrix: 1=ROI 0~ROI).

This mask can then be dot-multiplied to each frame to remove everything outside your ROI. Then continue to do the processing.

More advanced methods can include un-distorting the ROI by transformation and correcting the rotation, then cropping the unwanted areas away leaving you with Just the rectangular ROI.

Comment: Thanks for the concept :) But I was more of asking about the code of how would I set that ROI in a single frame then dot multiply it to each frame. Among the many ways/functions to set a ROI (roipoly,impoly imfreehand,imrect) which one is more suitable to my goal? And I would like to retain the whole image frame w/o cropping anything. It's just there would be a ROI bounded by a rectangular box where all the processing would happen in the video

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/trainingimagelabeler-app.html ? Several Computer Vision functions (see detectMSERFeatures for example) support an ROI input, where you can specify an ROI within which the function operates. This will not make you crop your image at all, but will only constrain processing in the ROI you specify.

Comment: I will  have a look at this ^